# phpmyadmin MySQL access error

Tags: mysql, iis-7, phpmyadmin, wamp

I am having issues attempting to access a local phpmyadmin; and I'm sure some people may have run into this issue before.

The issue seems to be arising from previous installations and configurations.

I have IIS installed, which naturally takes up port 80. However I have successfully installed WAMP and attached it to port 8080 so as to avoid conflicts. I have installed phpmyadmin to run from both platforms, however neither is working.

Through IIS the browser throws a 403.14 - Forbidden error whilst through WAMP phpmyadmin returns the following message

> MySQL said:
>
> 1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

I believe that at least one of these errors is due to an earlier installation of Wordpress through WebMatrix (which has gone predominantly unused) which changed the MySQL (5.1) username and password defaults.

Googling the issue resulted in what seemed a promising source which claimed that one can edit a file called config.inc.php which contains the password details which are used by phpmyadmin to log into the local MySQL db. However, I couldn't find such a file (instead one named config.sample.inc.php which contained some similar information contained in the tutorial, but crucially without the relevant password field).

This isn't an absolutely critical issue as hosted dbs are ultimately necessary, but local versions nevertheless ease development.

Comment: Create the missing config file from the sample, put your username / password in it.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in case you do not find config.inc.php then you can create one..

for details you may check [this link](http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Quick_Install#Manually)..